# What does "vorm" mean?

Tags: translation, usage

In the sentence:

> Früher habe ich immer Angst vorm Fliegen gehabt.

What does "vorm" mean?

Dictionary says it means "vor Mittags," but I don't think it fits here.

Comment: While the others are right that this is a contraction of "vor dem", note that if (and only if) you put a period after this, it actually *is* the abbreviation for "vormittags", which means "before noon".

Comment: There is nothing in this question that could not be answered by a quick internet search of trusted sources, like Duden, Oxford Dictionaries, etc. Why post this as a question?

Comment: @Mac is correct, but that wouldn't fit with the OP's example sentence. Either OP ignored a period or looked up weird dictionaries instead of https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/vorm and https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vorm

Answer (score 13):

It is a shortened `vor dem`:

```
Früher habe ich immer Angst vor dem Fliegen gehabt.
```

See also:

- [Duden.de: vorm](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorm)
- [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vorm) (includes references to other sources)

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that *vorm* is a colloquial form (umgangssprachlich).

Answer (score 6):

It's a contraction of *vor dem*. It’s similar to shortening *von dem* to *vom*.

Answer (score 3):

"vorm" is the short form of "vor dem"

> Ich stehe `vorm` Haus

I am `in front of` the house.

> Ich esse Sinigang `vorm` Zubettgehen.

I am eating sinigang `before` bed.

> Ich habe Angst `vorm` Fliegen

`I am scared of` flying.

Comment: "vor dem" does not always mean "in front of" -- for example "Ich habe Angst vor dem Hund"

Comment: on a sidenote... Zubettgehen is rarely used in written language as there are many shorter and easier to remember alternatives. I also do not hear it in spoken Language as a matter of fact, but that might be due to my age and the fact that I am from south germany..